# Swap the 2 colums in output ----Sed or Awk?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, swap

Input file:

```
GET /static_register_ad_request_1_2037_0_0_0_1_1_4_8335086462.gif?pa=99439_50491&country=US&state_fips_code=US_CA&city_name=Los%2BAngeles&dpId=2&dmkNm=apple&dmlNm=iPod%2Btouch&osNm=iPhone%2BOS&osvNm=5.1.1&bNm=Safari&bvNm=null&spNm=SBC%2BInternet%2BServices&kv=0_0&sessionId=0A80187E0138A0AE42E4DE3F783E7A08&sdk_version=4.0.5.6%20&domain=805AOEtUaMu&ad_catalog=99439_50491&make=APPLE&width=320&height=460&slot_type=PREROLL&model=iPod%20touch%205.1.1&iabcat=artsandentertainment&iabsubcat=music&age=113&gender=2&zip=92869 HTTP/1.1
```

Output file:

```
domain  sdk_version

805AOEtUaMu 4.0.5.6%20
```

I could use `sed -n 's/.*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*domain=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p'` to get the result, but sdk_version in first column, what I need is swap the sdk_version and domain columns in outputfile.

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you so much in advance:)

Comment: I've edited the question because bold characters don't work inside code tags, so those `**` between *domain* and *sdk_version* words made the regexp to fail.

Comment: Use `/\2 \1/` in the replacement portion of the `sed` regex?

Comment: Please don't edit-delete your own questions, it is not kind to those who have taken their time to answer and add to the community knowledge. If for some reason you really cannot stand to have this exist, please contact a moderator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        FS = "&";
    } 
    { 
        for ( i = 15; i <= 16; i++ ) { 
            split( $i, f, /=/ ); 
            printf( "%s ", f[2] ); 
        } 
    } 
    END { 
        printf "\n"; 
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
4.0.5.6%20 805AOEtUaMu
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap your backreferences:

```
sed -n 's/.*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*domain=\([^&]*\).*/\2 \1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle arbitrary order, I would suggest switching to `awk` or Perl.

```
perl -ne 'm/[?&]domain=([^&]+)/ && $d = $1;
    m/[?&]sdk_version=([^&]+) && $s = $1;
    print "$d\t$s\n"' logfile
```